# Completeness of Probability Distribution as a Measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space
and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function, i.e., it is a random variable.
Then, in the book

"Bernt Øksendal, stochastic differential equations: an introduction with applications, Springer-Verlag, 2003,"

it is said that $X$ induces the probability space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}, \mu_X)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, 
and $\mu_X: \mathcal{B} \to [0, 1]$ is the probability measure called the distribution given by
\begin{equation}
   \mu_X(B) \doteq \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) 
\end{equation}
for any $B \in \mathcal{B}$. My question is that is $\mu_X$ a complete measure? Since $\mathbb{P}$ is assumed complete, I think $\mu_X$ would be also complete, but I stuck with its proof. Perhaps, one need to show that 
\begin{equation}
   \mu_X(B) = 0 \textrm{ and } C \subset B \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; 
   C \in \mathcal{B},
\end{equation}
which obviously implies $\mu_X(C) = 0$ by monotonicy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the image measure of a random variable with respect to a complete measure is, in general, not complete.

---

Consider $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1))$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and denote by $((0,1),\bar{\mathcal{B}}(0,1),\bar{\lambda})$ its completion. Define

$$X: ((0,1),\bar{\mathcal{B}}(0,1),\bar{\lambda}) \to ((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),\lambda), x \mapsto x.$$

Obviously, $X$ is measurable and the underlying probability space is, by construction, complete. However, the image measure

$$\mu_X(B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \lambda(B), \qquad B \in \mathcal{B}(0,1)$$

is **not** complete (because the space $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),\lambda)$ is not complete).

---

More generally: Consider any random variable $$X:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \to (X,\mathcal{B},\mu_X)$$ such that $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu_X)$ is not complete. Then $$X: (\Omega,\bar{\mathcal{A}},\bar{\mathbb{P}}) \to (X,\mathcal{B},\mu_X)$$ is obviously still a random variable; the underlying probability space is complete, but $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu_X)$ is not complete.

Comment: I cannot understand why $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \lambda(B)$. And, in the general case, I assumed $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ a complete probability space and wanted to show that $\mu_X = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B))$ is complete or not. I think you just assumed that $\mu_X$ is not complete and then state that $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu_X)$ is not complete. Can you be more specific for them?

Comment: @JaeYoungLee concerning your 1st question: Since $X$ is the identity, we have $X^{-1}(B)=B$. Hence, as $\mathbb{P}$ is defined as Lebesgue measure (restriced to $(0,1)$), we have $$\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(B)= \lambda(B).$$

Comment: @ saz In your example, I think we just have $\mathbb{P}(B) = \lambda(B)$ almost surely, not for every measure zero set $B$ (since $\lambda$ is not complete). Intituively, $\mu_X$ seems to be complete since $\mathbb{P}$ is complete and $\mu_{X}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B)$. (Please comment on this if I am wrong).

Comment: @JaeYoungLee Yes, you are wrong. $\mu_X$ is **not** complete. We (hopefully) agree that $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu_X) = ((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),\lambda)$ (in the given example). This measure space is **not** complete. However, we can always(!) consider the completion of this measure space and, in this case, this gives the underlying probability space, the completion of the lebesgue measure. (And note that the statement "$\mathbb{P}(B) = \lambda(B)$ almost surely" doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @ saz I agree with your statement that $\mu_X$ is not complete. On the other hand,  ``$\mathbb{P}(B)=λ(B)$ almost surely'' means it holds except for some $\mathbb{P}$-measure zero sets. So it definitely agrees with your statement \begin{equation} \mu_X(B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(B) = \lambda(B) \;\; \textrm{for any } B \in \mathcal{B}(0, 1). \end{equation} I also want to mention that $\lambda$ is called a Borel measure and its completion $\tilde \lambda$ is called a Lebesgue measure for preventing confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee I know what "almost surely" means; that's not the point. But both $\mathbb{P}(B)$ and $\lambda(B)$ are constants; they do not depend on $\omega$ ... so there is no such thing as "almost surely". Or do you also say $\frac{1+1}{2} = 1$ almost surely? Anyway, it seems that our discussion leads nowhere; if you are lucky someone also will write an answer which is more to your liking.

Comment: @ saz Thank you for your comment. I understand what you mean and you are absolutely right. On the other hand, I have a concern about the fact that \begin{equation} \mu_X(B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)) = \mathbb{P}(B) = \bar \lambda (B) \end{equation} that also holds for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(0,1)$. This may lead to a mis-conclusion by the fact that $\bar \lambda(B)$ is complete.

Comment: @ saz At the end, I found that $\mu_X$ is even NOT defined for some sets $B \in \mathcal{\bar B}(0,1)$ since by the definition of a measurable function, $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{\bar B}(0,1)$ does not hold for $B \not \in \mathcal{B}(0, 1)$. Therefore, $\mu_X(B)$ is not complete since it is not defined for some measure zero sets $B$ in $\mathcal{\bar B}(0, 1)$ such that $B\cap C \neq 0$ for some $C \in \mathcal{\bar B}(0,1) \setminus \mathcal{B}(0,1)$.

Comment: @JaeYoungLee Yeah, but that's exactly what it means that a measure is not complete.

Comment: Yes. The conclusion that $\mu_X$ is not complete follows only from the definition of a measurable function.